# spatial join polygon within polygon does not work using sjoin on python

Tags: python, join, spatial, geopandas

I am trying to perform a spatial join using sjoin
leftdf: OSM_with_INE_ESPG32729_6_BGRI

```
print(len(OSM_with_INE_ESPG32729_6))
print(type(OSM_with_INE_ESPG32729_6))
print(OSM_with_INE_ESPG32729_6.crs)

1358642
<class 'geopandas.geodataframe.GeoDataFrame'>
epsg:32729
```

right df: BGRI

```
print(len(BGRI))
print(type(BGRI))
print(BGRI.crs)
255844
<class 'geopandas.geodataframe.GeoDataFrame'>
EPSG:32729
```

Both dfs have polygons. the left are buildings and the right are administrative areas.
(buidings are within the admnistrative areas)

When I run:

```
OSM_with_INE_ESPG32729_6_BGRI = OSM_with_INE_ESPG32729_6.sjoin(BGRI, how="left", predicate='within')
```

the resulting dataframe has some building without the admnistrative area:

[image: print screen from jupyter lab with the resulting dataframe and one example building that must have the admnistrative area assigned]

When I open both layers on QGIS I can see that some buildings (left df) have no area assigned (right df) but they should

[image: here it is on QGIS:]

zoom:

[image: zoom:]

Comment: Can you report it to https://github.com/geopandas/geopandas/issues and share the relevant bit of your data?

Comment: yes, I will do it